# Laravel 5.6 Testing File Uploads (Unable to find a file at path [file.txt])

Tags: php, phpunit, ubuntu-16.04, laravel-5.6

I am new to laravel, I can run successfully my file uploader, it uploads successfully my file, but the unit test fails, here is my code:

**UploadTest.php**

```
public function testUploadFile()
{
    $fileSize = 1024; // 1mb
    $fileName = 'file.txt';

    Storage::fake('files');
    $response = $this->json('POST', '/webservice/upload', [
        'file' => UploadedFile::fake()->create($fileName, $fileSize)
    ]);

    Storage::disk('files')->assertExists($fileName);
    Storage::disk('files')->assertMissing($fileName);
}
```

**FileUploadController**

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('file');
    if ($file == null) {
      return view('fileupload', 
        ['submitClickedMsg' => "Please select a file to upload."]);
    }

    $path = $file->storeAs('files', $file->getClientOriginalName(), 'local');
    return response()->json([
      'path' => $path
    ]);
}
```

**filesystem.php**

```
'disks' => [
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        ],
    ],
```

Help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With `Storage::fake('files')` you would fake a so called disk named 'files'. In your filesystems.php is no disk declared named 'files'.

In your FileUploadController you are saving to the subdirectory 'files' on your 'local' disk, so for making your test work, just fake this disk:

```
Storage::fake('local');
```

Also use this disk then for the assertions:

```
Storage::disk('local')->assertExists('files/' . $fileName);
```

In the testing environment the path will be `storage/framework/testing/disks` and not below `storage/app` directly.

Comment: Exactly the two points that are not obvious from the documentation.